# KalmanFilter(6,2,0) transition matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, tracking, kalman-filter

I am working on a object tracking project and I want to improve the results I am getting using a Kalman filter.

I have found a lot of examples on the internet which are working but I really want to understand what is behind it.

Using opencv, here is a part of the code :

```
KalmanFilter KF(6, 2, 0);
Mat_ state(6, 1); 
Mat processNoise(6, 1, CV_32F);
...
KF.statePre.at(0) = mouse_info.x;
KF.statePre.at(1) = mouse_info.y;
KF.statePre.at(2) = 0;
KF.statePre.at(3) = 0;
KF.statePre.at(4) = 0;
KF.statePre.at(5) = 0;
KF.transitionMatrix = *(Mat_(6, 6) << 1,0,1,0,0.5,0, 0,1,0,1,0,0.5, 0,0,1,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1,0,1, 0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0,1);
KF.measurementMatrix = *(Mat_(2, 6) << 1,0,1,0,0.5,0, 0,1,0,1,0,0.5);
```

This one gives smoother results than a  KalmanFilter(4,2,0) but I don't really understand why.
Can someone explain me what is behind this (6,6) transition matrix ?

EDIT : The solution is probably [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion) but obviously I am not good enough to find it by myself ...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a state vector **X** made up of 6 components, the first two of which are the x and y position of an object; let's assume that the other 4 are their velocities and accelerations:

**X** = [x, y, v_x, v_y, a_x, a_y] <sup>t</sup>

In the Kalman filter, your next state, **X**<sub>t+1</sub>, is equal to the previous state **X**<sub>t</sub> multiplied by the transition matrix **A**, so with the transition matrix you posted, you would have:

x <sub>t+1</sub> = x <sub>t</sub> + v_x <sub>t</sub> + 0.5 a_x <sub>t</sub>

y <sub>t+1</sub> = y <sub>t</sub> + v_y <sub>t</sub> + 0.5 a_y <sub>t</sub>

v_x <sub>t+1</sub> = v_x <sub>t</sub> + a_x <sub>t</sub>

v_y <sub>t+1</sub> = v_t <sub>t</sub> + a_t <sub>t</sub>

a_x <sub>t+1</sub> = a_x <sub>t</sub>

a_y <sub>t+1</sub> = a_y <sub>t</sub>

Which are the discrete approximation of the equations of an object moving with constant acceleration if the time interval between the two states is equal to 1 (and that's why it makes sense to suppose that the other four variables are velocities and accelerations).

This is a Kalman filter that allows for faster variations in the velocity estimation, so it introduces a lower delay than a (4, 2, 0) filter, which would use a constant velocity model.

Comment: Thanks, I came up with the same conclusion.